# How to filter out warning info

Tags: python

My code imports a function(import_function) from the other module(written by other guys).

```
ret = import_function(arg1,arg2)
```

The function will PRINT some warning info when it runs(the function uses print() to display the warning messages).
The question is: how can I filter out all these warning info?

I have tried the following way, but it doesn't work.

```
console_redirect = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = os.devnull
ret = import_function(arg1,arg2)
sys.stdout = console_redirect
```

Comment: sys.stdout != sys.stderr

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue with with sample code you provided is that `os.devnull` is a string; not a file object. You need to wrap it in an `open()`.  Like this:

```
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
ret = import_function(arg1,arg2)
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

there is no need to backup the original stdios, they are retained in `sys.__stdin__`, `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__syserr__`

If you are sure the output is coming out on stdout (via the `print` statement) replace stderr with stdout.

Comment: This will swallow *all* output to the file being redirected, and leave it silenced if an exception occurs.